# how to find the slope in excel for every six rows considering of all sample

Tags: excel

I have data with 57000 rows (windspeed and time) and i want to use the slope fuction for every six rows, my results will be 57000/6=9500 rows. Do you know how to do this in excel?
I want something like that

[image]

but for every six rows!!!

Comment: Although you are new here and probably not familiar with the etiquette here, it is a basic rule of human communication that one shows at least any kind of reaction if one asked a question and someone tries helping and answers that question. Simply not reacting looks very ungrateful for the one who had tried helping.

Answer (score 0):

Since `SLOPE` needs two ranges, I understand the requirement "every six rows" so that the first `SLOPE` calculates from row 2 to row 7, the second `SLOPE` calculates from row 8 to row 13, the third `SLOPE` calculates from row 14 to row 19 and so on.

This can be achieved using two helper columns calculating the row numbers and then `INDEX` functions calculating the two ranges.

Example:

[image]

Formulas:

`D3` downwards: `=$E2+1`

`E2` downwards: `=$D2+5`

`F2` downwards:

```
=SLOPE(INDEX($A:$A,$D2):INDEX($A:$A,$E2),INDEX($B:$B,$D2):INDEX($B:$B,$E2))
```